# Using Postgres \COPY function with TSV format

Tags: copy

I am getting `ERROR: COPY format "tsv" not recognized` when trying to copy file contents with `psql \copy` function. For some reason Postgres does not know TSV format?

Command that I am running is:
`psql -h <host> -U <user> -d <db> -c "\copy table_name (column1, column2, column3) FROM '/path/to/file.tsv' WITH (FORMAT TSV, FORCE_NULL(column2));"`

Tried to search around the issue, but all seem to be related to `FORMAT CSV` issues.

Answer (score 5):

Seems that you can also import TSV formatted files with `FORMAT CSV` command in PostgreSQL. Changing ending of my command to: `(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER E'\t');"` seems to work fine, as the delimiter is specified as tabbed delimiter.